# How to deserialize Vector of int using QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, deserialization

```
QVector<int> *l_iVec = new QVector<int>();

l_iVec->push_back(10);
l_iVec->push_back(20);
l_iVec->push_back(30);
l_iVec->push_back(40);

QDataStream dataStream;
dataStream<<l_iVec; //successfully build 

dataStream>>l_iVec; //getting error on this line

 error: invalid operands to binary expression ('QDataStream' and 'QVector<int> *') dataStream>>l_iVec;
               ~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~
```

I am trying to deserialize vector using qdatastream but get following error and unable to see the problem of error.It is serialize successfully with no error.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize vector or pointer to vector?

Comment: i am successful to serialize vector but not pointer to vector.I am trying both.

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

```
QVector<int> *l_iVec = new QVector<int>();
```

There is no good reason to allocate `QVector` dynamically, it is already a tiny wrapper to dynamically allocated data. You can return it by value efficiently, as the operation will not involve a deep copy. For situations you need to pass by reference, use a reference and not a pointer.

Secondly, as a result of your odd choice of allocation, you are currently not serializing and deserializing the vector data, but the value of the pointer to it. Dereference the pointer at the very least, or better off, don't use a pointer in the first place.

```
QDataStream &   operator<<(QDataStream &out, const QVector<T> &vector)
QDataStream &   operator>>(QDataStream &in, QVector<T> &vector)
```

As you see, the data stream operators take in a vector reference, not a vector pointer, and if your current serialization "works" that's probably a case of conversion, where the pointer is treated like an integer.

Comment: With your answer I am successful in serialize and deserialize vector of int. But I am unable to display deserialize vector using loop, for example                       
           for(int iVec : l_iVec)
             cout<<l_iVec<<endl;

Comment: No l_iVect is deserialize vector (dataStream>>l_iVec) and not a pointer to a vector.

Comment: Well it should work. Check your code, or whether your build is stuck, you may need to clean up the build and rebuild. Qt gets stuck quite often.